# fft phase plot of pure sine function, why so messy?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, matlab

I am plotting the phase plot of $sin(2*pi*60*x)$ in the frequency domain. Ideally, we should only see two peaks. How come this is not the case in matlab?

```
Fs=1/0.001;
x=0:1/Fs:1.8-1/Fs;

close all;

A=sin(60*2*pi.*x);
B=sin(180*2*pi.*(x)+pi/2);
fa=fftshift(fft(A));
fb=fftshift(fft(B));
f=linspace(-0.5, 0.5, length(x))*Fs;
figure;
subplot(2,1,1);
plot(f,abs(fa));
subplot(2,1,2);
plot(f,abs(fb));

figure;
subplot(2,1,1);
plot(f,radtodeg(angle(fa))); xlim([57,62]);
subplot(2,1,2);
plot(f,radtodeg(angle(fb))); xlim([177 185]);
```

---

### [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing two peaks in the magnitude plot, just as you should.

The reason you're not seeing two peaks in the angle plot is that the complex-argument function is ill-conditioned near zero. That is, a number that is "close to zero" doesn't necessarily have an angle that's close to zero.

So, even though `fa` and `fb` are  good approximations of the corresponding transform, their arguments might differ from what they should be wherever their magnitude should hit zero.

Comment: so, what can I do to produce a clean phase plot that has "expected" two peaks?

Comment: Here's one fix: take each of the ffts and, wherever the magnitude of the fft dips below some threshold (say, $10^{-6}$) round the fft down to zero.  That should give you a nice plot, assuming Matlab defines `angle(0)` to be 0.

Comment: I think at those particular frequencies, the phase measurement is not right

Comment: Yes... that is exactly what I explained in my answer. My fix is to look for those frequencies and fix the phase measurement by rounding the complex number at that frequency to zero.

Comment: Usually, this isn't an issue since when the magnitude is zero, the phase doesn't matter.

Comment: I mean, at the particular frequency where the magnitude peaks, the phase angle at those particular frequency isn't correct.

Comment: Oh... well that's a different problem then. What angle does Matlab give at the spike?

Comment: please see my update

Comment: could you please confirm this?  It was correct,..... I just realized thee is +90 degree for sin, and nothing when you change to cosine

Comment: Yes, sine gives you a phase shift at the peak and cosine does not.  In fact, it looks to me like Matlab might have it right after all.