# How can I derive the magnitude of the fourier transform of sine wave?

Tags: complex-numbers, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

building on this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2152573/845257 . I was deriving the Fourier transform of sine wave  `y(t) = sin(2.pi.f.t)` and I got it right. Now, I want to derive the magnitude I can't find how he got the magnitude of the sine Fourier transform like that.

Comment: The magnitude of **what** exactly are your referring to? If you refer to the other question, then I suggest that you should ask in a comment on the answer there.

Comment: Ok, I edited my question I want to know how the man with that answer derived that magnitude.

Comment: I am sorry I can't comment there as my reputation is still low.

Comment: So is your question, "why is the magnitude of $-i/2$ equal to $1/2$?"

Comment: What I know is that to get the magnitude of (a + i*b) is (Magnitude = sqrt(a^2 + b^2))

Comment: To apply this on the Fourier transform of sine it should be [Magnitude = sqrt((0)^2 + (-delta(W-Wo) + delta(W+Wo))^2/4)]

Comment: This can't lead me to the right answer so, I don't know what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is well known that if $\,z\,$ is a complex number with real
part $\,a\,$ and imaginary part $\,b\,$ then the magnitude of
$\,z\,$ is $\,\sqrt{a^2+b^2}.\,$ so far so good. Note that if
you have a complex function $\,f(\omega)\,$ then to get its
magnitude you have to find the real and imaginary part **for each** value of $\,\omega.\,$ In the case of interest here we have
$$ f(\omega) := -\frac{i}{2}\delta(\omega -\omega_0) + \frac{i}{2}\delta(\omega +  \omega_0). $$ For each value of $\,\omega\,$ we have to find the imaginary and real parts of $\,f(\omega).\,$
Notice the Dirac delta function $\,\delta()\,$ which means
that the function is zero everywhere **except** at the two
values $\,\omega=\omega_0\,$ and $\,\omega=-\omega_0\,$, which implies the magnitude is zero also
except at the two values. Now
evaluate the functional expression for those two
exceptional values of $\,\omega\,$ and you will get
the expression given in the answer to the question
you refer to.

Comment: So you mean it's calculated like a for loop over all the domain of omega and this will result in zeros in all values of omega except for two values of omega when W=Wo and W=-Wo which will get that result.

Comment: Thank you very much @Somos this was really helpful.